# How to stop a downstream job from being run if it is waiting for upstream job to finish in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins-plugins

I have 2 projects :-
1. Project A
2. Project B

Project A is the upstream project and Project B is the downstream project. 
Project B waits if Project A is already building.
Project A triggers Project B on finishing successfully.

Now here is the scenario:-

Project A is building and Project B is waiting for Project A to finish. Project B immediately gets triggered once Project A finishes. But, Project A also triggers Project B on finishing. So, basically Project B runs twice.

My requirement is - only the job (of Project B) triggered by upstream project (Project A) should run and not the one which is waiting for the upstream project (Project A) to finish. The waiting job should get purged from the queue.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it.

I suggest to check out this plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin

It has covered my most sadistic needs up to this date. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried blocking the build when upstream project is running?
[image]

Comment: Project B is already blocked when Project A is building...But when project A finishes, it triggers Project B..which means now 2 jobs for Project B are there(one in queue and one in building state).